# can i create an user database on google app engine where i can store user details using java

Tags: database, google-app-engine

i am new on google app engine . i want to develop an such type of app in which a user can login and and app can store data on the datasore. 
can i create an user database on google app engine where i can store user details using java ?
i know how to create a simple page using Eclipse IDE without datastore .
i searched on google a lot but find only one link (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/
)

it will be good for me if u give me some sample code link

Answer (score 0):

could you please be a little bit more specific ?

You have two choices for storing data : The datastore or Google Cloud SQL. In both cases, you can store whatever information you like.

Maybe best if you are very new to Google App Engine is to read this article : [Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify)

Objectify is a framework which can be used to store the data in the datastore. It is extremely easy to use, well documented and there is a very good user community.

Comment: thanks for ans , but as in mysql we create a Table "user_detail" with two columns 'user_name' and 'password' . similar thing i want to do in google app engine . 
one more thing , as in jsp we connect database with JDBC driver , how i can connect my app with data store ?